# Скопировать отфильтрованные данные на другую страницу с помощью =vlookup в excel

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть workbook  со списком студентов, которые прошли/не прошли курсы. 
Прошел - "Оk", не прошел - "NO".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо отфильтровать имена прошедших определенный курс и скопировать их на другой лист.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно сделать с помощью =VLOOKUP и/или =IF формулы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант1. Без формул**

Отфильтровать список по столбцу `Status` (значение *Ok*). Копировать , вставить в другой диапазон. Вставятся только видимые данные.

**Вариант2. Формулы простые**

Для работы с формулами таблицу нужно подготовить.

Добавить столбец левее столбца `Student` (Теперь `Student` в столбце `В`). В `A2` формула:

```
=ЕСЛИ(D2="Ok";МАКС(A$1:A1)+1)
```

Растягиваем на все строки таблицы. Получаем нумерацию нужных строк.

В таблице, где результат, формула первого столбца (`№ п/п`):

```
=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(A1)>МАКС(лист_исходник!A$1:A$100);"";СТРОКА(A1))
```

Чтобы не считать *МАКС* в каждой строке, его можно вычислить в отдельной ячейке, а в формулу подставить ссылку.

Основная формула для трех столбцов (ввести в верхнюю левую ячейку (`B2`) и размножить формулу по строкам и столбцам:

```
=ЕСЛИ($A2="";"";ВПР($A2;лист_исходник!$A$1:$D$100;СТОЛБЕЦ(B1);0)
```

**Вариант3. Формула массива**

Без добавления столбца в исходную таблицу.

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ИНДЕКС(A$2:A$100;НАИБОЛЬШИЙ(ЕСЛИ($D$2:$D$100="Ok";СТРОКА($D$2:$D$100)-1);СТРОКА(A1)));"")
```

Формулу записываем в верхнюю левую ячейку новой таблицы. Не выходя из режима редактирования ячейки, вводим как формулу массива - нажимаем `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` - формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками.

Копируем ячейку по строкам и столбцам.